# How to fix build.gradle error while using " classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' "

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is my android gradle file. I am getting error android gradle plugin that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testcompile' was added in 1.1.0.). How can I fix this problem.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
}
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your `dependencies` block you have to remove this line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

This line should be used in the `buildscript` block, something like:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. after the changes made as suggested by you

Comment: You should post the build.gradle in the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

After the correction now the build. gradle looks like this and now i ge the the error as " Error:(20, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:

The project 'WeatherApp' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project

The project 'WeatherApp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` from there and add it to your top-level `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. after the changes made as suggested by you